Espresso Test for Activity with Forced Portrait Mode Fails Orientation Assertion
I am testing an Android app using Espresso, and I have an activity that should only be displayed in portrait mode. To enforce this, I programmatically lock the activity in portrait mode when it is started. This works correctly in the app during normal usage.
However, when testing this behavior with Espresso, I encounter an issue. In my test, I simulate a rotation using the following code:
val device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
device.setOrientationRight()

This successfully rotates the device to landscape. Then, I navigate to the activity that locked to portrait mode. The activity appears correctly in portrait mode as expected.
To verify the orientation in my test, I use this code:
val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
val orientation = context.resources.configuration.orientation
assertEquals(Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, orientation)

However, the test fails because the orientation returned is Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE, even though the activity is displaying the portrait layout correctly.
It seems the device’s orientation remains in landscape, and the system-level configuration is not updated to reflect the forced portrait mode of the activity. Since there is only one layout file (portrait), I cannot verify the orientation by checking which layout is displayed.
How can I test this behavior correctly? Is there a way to assert that the activity is truly locked in portrait mode even though the device’s orientation has been changed?

"How can I test this behavior correctly?" -- try not using the application Context. You changed the orientation of an activity, not the app. So, test using the activity Context, assuming that you can access it (e.g., ActivityTestRule).

As mentioned in the comment, the test works when using the Activity context and checking the orientation.
    val orientation = activity.resources.configuration.orientation

